# Angular Material Table - hide or show components in row

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a simple material table data with two columns, the first is a column containing a mat select component while the second is an action column containing a button.

I would like the button in the action column to be hidden until the user clicks the mat-select component.

I have implement a click handler for the mat-select:

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="transactions">

    <!-- Category Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="category">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Category </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let transaction">
            <mat-form-field floatLabel="never">
                <mat-select [(value)]="transaction.category" placeholder="Category" (click)='onClick'>
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let classItem of classes" [value]="classItem.id">
                        {{classItem.class}}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Action Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Action </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <button mat-flat-button color="accent">Accent</button>
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>


    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let transaction"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

I would like to know how I would access the mat button component belonging to the same row so that I may hide / unhide it as I require.

Comment: Could you please add the code of the material table also?

Comment: Edited the question to include the material table code

Comment: A mat-table is feed by a datasource or by an array. When in a mat-cell your write <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">` in "element" you has the whole object of this row. Your object can has a property "justSelected", that you change when change the mat-select and you can use *ngIf="element.justSelected" or another similar way.

Comment: Thanks, I thought as much but wondered if there was a way to access the component visibility property without binding it to the data source.  I'll proceed as you have suggested for now